Simplify None Check without Repeating XML Path
I'm trying to parse out some XML, where some tags aren't always in the XML. I was getting an error when trying to get the text, as I can't get .text when it's None
Seems like there should be a better way to handle this? This is also just one value, I have many that I need to extract I don't think repeating the XML Path is great solution
This returns "" if value is None and returns the actual text if exists:
myArr.append([
"" if properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id1", namespaces) is None else properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id1", namespaces).text,
"" if properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id2", namespaces) is None else properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id2", namespaces).text,
"" if properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id3", namespaces) is None else properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id3", namespaces).text
(... many more ...)
])


Maybe start with value = properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id", namespaces) then you can do value = value.text if value else ""

This is true, though in my actual code I would have to have many variables, I was hoping for something other languages have like coalesce or ??

Would the walrus operator suffice to clear it up? value = tmp.value if (tmp := properties.find("link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id", namespaces)) else ""

Ah I see, the way I worded the question yes this would work. I'll edit to remove the variable and add more context. The reason I'm looking for inline is because all of these values are appending to an array

based on your edit, I would use the answer by @treuss I think. Let me see if there is a nice clean way to use map()

Just write yourself a small utility function:
def get_xpath_value(xmlel, xpath, namespaces={}, fallback=""):
    if (el := xmlel.find(xpath, namespaces)) is not None:
        return el.text
    else:
        return fallback

value = get_xpath_value(properties, "link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id", namespaces=namespaces)


Yeah that's a good idea, requires a function but at least it's one line to get

Given a long list of paths you might use a comprehension to build the results like:
my_ids = [
    "link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id1",
    "link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id2",
    "link[@title='myTitle']/a:inline/feed/entry/content/b:properties/c:Id3"
]
myArr = [tmp.text if (tmp:=properties.find(my_id, namespaces)) else "" for my_id in my_ids]

of course you could use the method proposed by @treuss here as well to clean it up even more.

Thank you this would also work, I think for my particular case will use @treuss suggestion

use both :-)  myArr = [get_xpath_value(properties, my_id, namespaces=namespaces) for my_id in my_ids]
